# How do I modify the effect of a button with another button in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create an app that adds, at first the value 1 to the textView.

Then I tried creating another button that doubles the value shown in the textview.

Everytime I press the first button, it should increment by 1 
and everytime I press the other button it should double that result.

But when I add 1 to the value again, the value goes back to the undoubled stage and increments by one.

I need to cover the operations by making a button that adds value X 
and the other button that multiplies that value of the button by 2.

This is the main.kt I made so far

```
    value.setText("" + id)

    plusBtn.setOnClickListener {
        value.setText("" + ++id)
    }

    doubleBtn.setOnClickListener {
        value.setText("" + 2*id) 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could solve the problem. You haven't saved the value in the variable. when you set the text to 2*id, the id variable is still the same.

```
value.setText("" + id)

plusBtn.setOnClickListener {
    value.setText("" + ++id)
}

doubleBtn.setOnClickListener {
    value.setText("" + 2*id)
    id=2*id; 
}
```

Comment: it does, but i need to make the second button perform the double on the first button. this is the tricky part

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... When you click the 1st button you increment it by 1 and the second button doubles it. The code I wrote above does exactly that. Maybe you should explain a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get updated value from **textView** when you click on any button.

Check following statements, I had written in Java but you may able to convert in kotlin.

```
plusBtn.setOnClickListener {
    id = Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString());
    value.setText("" + ++id)
}

doubleBtn.setOnClickListener {
    id = Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString());
    value.setText("" + 2*id) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are just setting the double value of id as text to the value, not assigning the double value to the id.
to do this you can either assign the 
    value.setText("" + 2*id) 
    id = Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString());
or 
   id = 2*id
   value.setText(id)

Answer (score 0):

I'm only answering because the other answers so far are convoluted (converting back and forth from Strings) or use needless repetition (calculating the doubled value twice).

When you use `++id`, you are using the increment operator, which adds one to the value in `id`, but also changes `id` to the new value. It is a shorthand way of writing what would normally take two lines of code. What you're doing is equivalent to

```
plusBtn.setOnClickListener {
    id = id + 1
    value.setText("" + id)
}
```

When you use `2*id`, you are calculating a new value, but you are not assigning this new value to `id`. There isn't a shorthand operator for doing both actions like there is for adding or subtracting one.

The simplest solution is to assign the new value before changing the text. So your second button listener becomes:

```
doubleBtn.setOnClickListener {
    id = id * 2
    value.setText("" + id) 
}
```

or, more succinctly:

```
doubleBtn.setOnClickListener {
    id *= 2
    value.setText("" + id) 
}
```